# Button open "tools image" instead of running code

Tags: excel, vba

When I press a VBA button in Excel, a new tab appears in the menu "TOOLS IMAGE" and under it: "FORMAT" (not sure about the translation, the french name is "outils image"):

[image]

The button is selected the same way as when the "creation mode" is selected (in french: "mode creation") and the macro is not executed. I have to open the macro editor to run the corresponding routine.

I used this file for weeks. The problem started yesterday. I have not done macro modification yesterday.

I suppose the file is in a kind of edit mode. I did not find anything about that googling.

Comment: Is (or was) it an Activex button?

Comment: @Rory: yes, there are all Activex Button

Comment: Then you are almost certainly running into the issue where the MSForms library gets updated on one machine and is incompatible with the temp files on another. See http://excelmatters.com/2014/12/10/office-update-breaks-activex-controls/ for some fixes or better yet, use Form controls instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps somehow your design mode got toggled, although I don't know how it could. Perhaps you should check in your VBE window if the following is on (button in orange):

[image]

Or in the developer tab:

[image]

If that fails, see if the macro is still linked to your button correctly by right clicking on it and selecting "View code" (for activeX buttons) or "Assign macro" for form control buttons.

Comment: I already check the design mode. But you're right, the macro is not assign anymore to the button. I think I will create a macro to create the button to assign automatically. I'll read a bit about that first and then fix my button. I'll come back when it's fix.